# How to parallelize function on list comprehension (and keep order)

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, list-comprehension, multiprocess

I have a list of 2d arrays (different lengths) to which I need to apply certain functions efficiently via list comprehension.

Since this is still not fast enough, the list comprehension needs to be parallelized.

What is the proper way to do that, with keeping the order of the slices (or "subarrays")?

```
def get_slice_max(arr): 
     '''
     get the slice, but replace every element with the maximum value that has occoured till(including) the iter so far.
     ''' 
     result = [arr[0]] 
     for i in range(1, len(arr)):  
         result.append(max(result[-1], arr[i])) 
     return result

result  = [get_slice_max(slice_)  for slice_ in a]
```

reproducable sample:

```
a = [ np.array(range(1, random.randint(3, 8))) for x in range(10000)]
```

Edit:
I need the parallelization for list comprehensions like those:

```
temp = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=10) # determines the sizes of the subarrays
A,B,C =  [ np.randint(0, high=1, size=x) for x in temp],
    [ np.random.uniform(size=x) for x in temp],
    [ np.random.uniform(size=x) for x in temp]
result = [ [y if x==1 else z for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)] 
              for  a, b, c  in zip(A, B, C,) ]

temp = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=10) # determines the sizes of the subarrays
D, E = [ np.random.uniform(size=x) for x in temp], [ np.randint(0, high=1, size=x) for x in temp]
[ [ x/y for x,y in zip(d,np.maximum.accumulate(get_slice_max(e))] for d, e in zip(D, E) ]
```

Comment: Don't code this yourself, but use well-established libraries coded in languages like C, like `numpy` and `pandas` - these have the operations you're looking for, or allow you to more efficiently apply your own.

Comment: in this case unfortunately not. :( already searched a few months ago.

Comment: Surely you found `numpy.maximum.accumulate()`? How does that not solve your problem?

Comment: this looks nice ^^ I'll try to implement it. and could you also teach me how to parallelize list comprehensions? (theres multiple functions which are a little bit more complicated that the one above) like:
result  = [ [ x/y for x,y in zip(profits,get_slice_max(lows))] for profits, lows    in zip(profitsSlices,lowDirection )  ] 
Where profitslices and lowDirection are lists of numpy arrays. (each array in profitslices is the same lenght as the array in lowDirection at the same index).
Edit: all the numbers in the funcs are float32

Comment: If you need to parallelise complicated operations, look into specialised libraries for doing just that - like Dask. I don't have an opinion on it and I'm not here to endorse it - in fact, I've never had to use it; but I do know it exists and I'd never even think about trying to write something from scratch knowing there's somebody out there that already solved the problem before me and probably did a pretty good job of it, given its project status.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.maximum.accumulate`:

```
# Sample
a = [np.random.randint(1, 10, np.random.randint(3, 8)) for _ in range(10000)]
a[:3]
# [array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 2, 8, 2, 9, 5]), array([5, 1, 7, 5])]

[np.maximum.accumulate(arr) for arr in a]
```

Output:

```
[array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]), array([5, 5, 7, 7])]
```

Validation:

```
all(np.array_equal(get_slice_max(arr), np.maximum.accumulate(arr)) for arr in a)
# True
```

Benchmark (about 6x faster):

```
%timeit [np.maximum.accumulate(arr) for arr in a]
# 6.07 ms ± 498 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit [get_slice_max(arr) for arr in a]
# 32.4 ms ± 11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```